# In thread, when loop too much times, Invoke waste a lot of time

Tags: multithreading, performance, delegates, invoke

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100,000; i++)
{
    threadEvent.Invoke(i, new EventArgs());// tell processbar value
}

 threadEvent += new EventHandler(method_threadEvent);
void method_threadEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int nowValue = Convert.ToInt32(sender);
        nowValueDelegate now = new nowValueDelegate(setNow);
        this.Invoke(now, nowValue);
    }
private void setNow(int nowValue)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Value = nowValue;
    }
private delegate void nowValueDelegate(int nowValue);
```

in the loop i do nothing, but it also waste alot of time !

why threadEvent.Invoke spend so much time ?

Comment: It is not true that “in the loop i do nothing”; you are calling `threadEvent.Invoke`. In fact, that is the only thing you do, so of course it is going to take 100% of the time.

Comment: This is just one example， I removed the other code， When updating processbar, it takes too much time, if I do not use Invoking，In fact, it can be quickly completed.

Comment: What do you want to hear? Invoking is expensive, as you discovered. Invoke less often. The progress bar does not have to be updated 100k times. Update it every 100ms.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking is an expensive operation, because it has to cross thread boundaries.

It's best to reduce the amount of invokes, by for instance only updating the progress bar for each percentage of work you do, rather than for each iteration of the loop. That way, only 100 updates need to be processed, rather than one for each iteration.

First thing you need to do is to calculate or estimate the current progress.
For a typical loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; ++i)
{
    ... // Work here
}
```

A good estimate of progress is `(i / someValue) * 100`, which gives the percentage of the loop that has been completed. To update the progress to the UI thread only when the next percentage has been reached you could do something in the line of:

```
int percentCompleted = 0;
threadEvent.Invoke(percentCompleted, new EventArgs()); // Initial progressbar value
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; ++i)
{
    int newlyCompleted = (i / someValue) * 100;
    if (newlyCompleted > percentCompleted)
            threadEvent.Invoke(percentCompleted, new EventArgs());
    percentCompleted = newlyCompleted;

    ... // Work here
}
```

Now finally, you could use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke to make sure the worker thread doesn't wait for the threadEvent to complete (`PostMessage` behaviour). This works well here because there is no return value from threadEvent that you need.

Comment: As you said,  are there ways to avoid ？  that is a good way updata processbar per 100 updata, but the data num is unknown.

Comment: @user1908725: You need to either calculate or estimate a progress percentage in your worker thread. Then every time your percentage goes up by 1 or more, you Invoke the update. This reduces the amount of updates that need to be sent, which is a good thing - you want to perform work, not spend time updating. To further increase performance, you could use BeginInvoke, rather than Invoke: Invoke blocks and waits until the UI thread has finished updating, whilst BeginInvoke posts the message and continuous immediately.

Comment: @user1908725: I edited my answer to address your questions with some sample code

Comment: Thanks. i use the first method. BeginInvoke I do not how to use.